# ASP On Error Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, asp-classic

In ASP JavaScript I am trying to form a statement (possibly an if statement) that will catch any error's that occur on any ASP page and when there is one it will redirect the page to an error page that will display the previous pages title and error number.

How can I identify the error and redirect to a new ASP page with the two pieces of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work fine:

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Response.Redirect("/path/to/page.asp?errnum=" & Err.Number & "&pagetitle=your%20page%20title"
End If
```

On your destination error page simply read the values from the querystring e.g. `Request.QueryString("errnum")`

Comment: That does allow me to run the page! Though when I try to cause an error in the code I am still prompted with a default error page and not the error page i have specified in your code above.

Comment: Ah sorry, you'll need to add `On Error Resume Next` at the top of your page so it will resume even when errors occur. You really should only do this in a development environment though, errors in your code should never be visible in a production environment unless it's an error that can't show the user something specific about a server. Also you'll want to make sure the error checking and redirect are at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Progress! Now when there is an error is resumes on with the loading the page, but it still isn't redirecting with this code (same as above): 
<%If Err.Number <> 0 Then Response.Redirect("/my/Error Page/ErrorPage.asp?errnum=" & Err.Number & "&pagetitle=your%20page%20title") End If %>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Hope this helps and solves your issue.

`<%If Err.Number <> 0 Then Response.Redirect("/my/Error Page/ErrorPage.asp?errnum=" & Err.Number & "&pagetitle=your%20page%20title", false) End If %>`